# Magento 2.1.10 ce Developer Documentation

Tags: frontend, development, documentation, magento-2.1.10

Where can I find the Developer Documentation for an older version of Magento, specifically, version 2.1.10.

Magento's website only has the DeVDocs for 2.2 and while these are okay I would they aren't exactly what I am looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the archive of the devdocs for 2.1.10 on the Magento github repo https://github.com/magento/devdocs/releases/tag/2.1.10.

You will have to download the arhive, unpack it and check the folder *guides/v2.1* and navigate through the subfolders of interest where you will find the markdown files used to build the devdocs pages.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: you are most welcome! cheers!